# Google Sheets: Find unique matches in two columns and transpose them to an array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns of data: names and number values. I want to find all existing unique combinations of names and values and transpose them as an array to another cell.

Let's say I start with this data set:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Brad | 1 |
| Bryan | 5 |
| Albert | 1 |
| Ronnie | 20 |
| Brad | 50 |
| Brad | 1 |
| Ronnie | 20 |

What I'm trying to return is something like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | 1 |
| Brad | 1 |
| Brad | 50 |
| Bryan | 5 |
| Ronnie | 20 |

Through some Googling, I was able to find and modify this query:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))&char(9)),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")))),char(9)))&"|"&TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""))&char(9),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))))),char(9)))),"|"))
```

It returns all *possible* combinations, but not just the existing combinations. I'm trying to avoid having to paste the possible combinations and run another check against the original columns. As the data set grows over time, listing all possible combinations could prove expensive.

How can I return only the existing combinations?

Comment: Always add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: See  [Should I include tags in title?](/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=arrayformula(sort(UNIQUE(A1:B8)))
```

Then you can see what you are trying to return.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. 
Fantastic! I was making it too complex. This works perfectly.

Comment: you don't really need the `ArrayFormula()` here. `sort(unique())` will work just fine.

Comment: @ztiaa Thank you. You are right, and actually the first version is  sort(unique()). I changed it because the same format may be helpful to understand in the question.